# How to "convince" Microsoft Teams to show websites logo in copied chat link

Tags: chat, graphical-logo

Does anybody know how to "convince" Microsoft Teams to show my websites logo in a copied link in a teams chat. It only shows the generic link icon:

[image: Screenshot copied link in Teams chat]

Thank you very much!

Comment: @haryshm writes in the MS-Dev-Blog:

"One of the most common ways to share content in Microsoft Teams is through links, be it for an update for that task you’re working on or for sharing the latest Game of Thrones trailer. For any publicly accessible link Teams already shows a preview of the link including information like an image, title and a description."

My question is: How must a publicly accessible website provide the image to be shown in Teams in the preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this meta-tag does the magic:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.blikk.it/blikk_gross.png">`

Found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams

Comment: Unfortunately this links goes 404